# Bitcoin core 0.19.1 RPC, 'sendtoaddress' not working!

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

Suppose this scenario:

> There are 2 wallets called `wallet1` and `wallet1` on the same node in `testnet` blockchain.
>
> `wallet1` balance: 0.001 BTC
>
> `wallet2` balance: 0 BTC

I am trying to send 0.001 BTCs from `wallet1` to `wallet2`; so I use the `sendtoaddress` command like this:

`bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=wallet1 sendtoaddress <wallet2 address> 0.001 "" "" true`.

This gives me a `txid` which none of the blockchain explorers like [live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet) can't recognize it!

> It deducts the coin from `wallet1` and I don't know where does it go!?

For solving this, I tried to get the transaction hex to broadcast it via some other platforms to check if the raw transaction is correct and it was OK and after broadcasting it via the other platform, blockchain explorers could detect the transaction id.

Here are my question:

1. Isn't just using `sendtoaddress` enough for sending coins?
2. Why the broadcasting process doesn't complete on my node?

Here is my `bitcoin.conf`:

```
[test]
prune=600
blocksonly=1
maxconnections=15
testnet=1
regtest=0

deprecatedrpc=accounts
deprecatedrpc=addwitnessaddress
deprecatedrpc=signrawtransaction
deprecatedrpc=validateaddress

minrelaytxfee=0.0001
maxmempool=200
maxreceiverbuffer=2500
maxsendbuffer=500
dbcache=16000

rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rpcallowip=--

rpcuser=--
rpcpassword=--

server=1
rest=1
daemon=1
```

Comment: If it works when you broadcast the same transaction via explorers, then there is likely an issue with how your node connects to the testnet - your peers might not be broadcasting/accepting your transaction, or you just might not be connected at all

Comment: @RaghavSood I think its connected because when I send bitcoin from an external wallet to my node based wallet, after confirmations, it detects the correct balance. I have searched about my problem and I think it might be because of the `bitcoin.conf`. I have used `blocksonly=1` in `test` block. Can it be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the parameter `blocksonly=1` in bitcoin config file. This prevents the node to broadcast transactions to the netwrok. I removed it and it works fine!